# app.dependency_overrides not working in test

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fastapi, pydantic, pydantic-settings

I have a project that uses FastApi and Pydantic-settings. While the injection of settings works fine i am not able to override them in test.

My settings look like this:

```
class LevelDBSettings(BaseSettings):
    """
    Settings for the levelDB database.
    """

    fetch_url: str
    """URL to fetch data from levelDB"""

    read_token: str
    """Token to authenticate against levelDB"""

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file="dev_default.env", env_file_encoding="utf-8")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.model_config)

def get_level_db_settings():
    """provide level db settings application wide. injectable via dependency injection"""
    return LevelDBSettings()
```

Injecting them also works fine:

```
def get_data_from_db(msn: str, start: datetime, end: datetime):
    request = FetchRequest(start, end, msn)
    settings = Annotated[LevelDBSettings, Depends(get_level_db_settings)]()
    # inject settings
```

As you see i put the method to get setings in settings class for 2 reasons:

- it just belongs here (my opinion)
- if put in file with app = FastAPI() i get circular dependency errors. because app imports routers that call methods that inject settings from fast api - circle

First question: is this a general problem? Can i only use "dependency_overrides" for methods in app? (How to inject arbitrary things and override them in tests?)

My test is this (separate path /tests/integration)

```
def get_test_level_db_settings():
    settings = LevelDBSettings()
    settings.fetch_url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v0/fetch"
    settings.read_token = "sometest"
    return settings

def test_fetch_data():

    app.dependency_overrides[get_level_db_settings] = get_test_level_db_settings
    ...
```

This test fails due to missing settings in pydantic-settings (it can not load env file because test runs in different folder)

How to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

`app.dependency_overrides` works only for replacing injected dependencies, i.e. `Depends` or `Annotated` parameters of your routes.

If your function/callable is not injected, you should use a different technique to "patch" it. I personally use [`patch` from `unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) when I cannot use `app.dependency_overrides`.

Note that you didn't provide an explicit example on how your settings are used in your routes. Maybe we can help you refactor your example to inject the settings as a dependency.

Comment: as steted i use Annotated ..Depends and injection works in code, but override does not work in test. currently i use load_dotenv to patch at least env values

Comment: Is `get_data_from_db()` the part where you do the dependency injection? `Depends(get_level_db_settings)` is supposed to be a route function parameter. You cannot call `Annotated[LevelDBSettings, Depends(get_level_db_settings)]()` from arbitrary location.

Comment: that mean dependency injection is not a general concept to be applied anywhere? because the injection actually works. as you see in my question settings = Annotated[LevelDBSettings, Depends(get_level_db_settings)]() works

Comment: _that mean dependency injection is not a general concept to be applied anywhere?_
In the context of FastAPI, no as the dependencies are resolved by the framework when calling your route (FastAPI calls your function with the resolved dependencies—not the opposite). Your example works because your dependency is not contextual, it just call the `get_level_db_settings()` function. If you try with contextual dependencies (e.g. route parameters or query string) you will see that it does not work. Anyways, I think this is just a matter of moving all your dependencies as route function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_data_from_db(msn: str, start: datetime, end: datetime):
    request = FetchRequest(start, end, msn)
    settings = Annotated[LevelDBSettings, Depends(get_level_db_settings)]()
    # inject settings
```

By using `Depends` inside function's body (not in the parameters of function) you lose some advantages of FastAPI dependencies, and one of them is `dependency_override`.

Try to move `Depends` to the path function parameters:

```
def get_data_from_db(
    msn: str, start: datetime, end: datetime,
    settings = Annotated[LevelDBSettings, Depends(get_level_db_settings)]
):
    ...
```